# Memory issue in an WPF application when using linq

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, dotmemory

I am currently hunting down memoryleaks in our application and when it comes to viewmodels that execute any linq queries I find an object in memory with that namespace. I am using dotMemory to do the inspection and it lists the object with a +<>c ending. I have not found any explanation what kind of object this is and if it is a real issue that this resides in memory, but I have found out that it is connected to the linq query. Code that reprodce this and as you can see the Linq query result is never used.

```
 public class myViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
 {

    public myViewModel()
    {
        var memissue = _dummyList.ToList().Any(c => c == false);
    }

    public string SomeBoundProperty
    {
        get { return _someBoundProperty; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _someBoundProperty) return;
            _someBoundProperty = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }
 }
```

Snapshot from dotmemory:
[image]

I hope that someone can explain what kind of object a +<>c is and maybe why it is not released from memory or is this just the way that Linq works?

Comment: ViewModel+<>c is a nested class automatically generated by compiler to represent a lamba used somewhere in the class ViewModel. In order to learn why it is not released double click on the row displayed on the screenshot and see what holds this instance in memory. dotMemory will tell you all about it.

Answer (score 0):

`.ToList()` enumerates the whole collection and stores a copy in memory. This is typically not useful if you aren't going to use all the information in the collection. Try removing `.ToList()` and see what happens. You should expect to see immediate savings.

To shed some light on the `+<>c` thing, I believe that comes from it being a generic type. I'm inferring from the code you provided that the type is really `List<Boolean>`.

Comment: +c<> comes from an anonymous method which captures local variables which are put into a compiler generated class. If you leak such things then you should look at your databinding to LINQ queries which are refernced by WPF objects.

Comment: @SaxxonPike Sorry I din't see that the ToList() was there. That was one attempt to see if it was released if I did a to list first. I other words same result without the .ToList().

Comment: @Alois Kraus I am not sure if I understand your reply as the viewmodel in my question is the complete viewmodel(forgot to add the list of 4 boolean values) and I don't use the result for anything. I don't bind to the linq query in any way. I have noticed that I don't get more copies of the object in memory and then I suspect this is how Linq will optimize the query next time I create a new instance of the viewmodel?

Comment: The type before the +c<> is the class, next comes the method in which it was declared. Look for the dataflow where your objects are referenced with the memory profiler to find the issue.

Comment: @Alois Kraus. My view and viewmodel are released from memory. The method left is a System.Func<Boolean. Boolean>. As I mentioned in previous reply I suspect that this is how Linq works where it adds an handle to it in memory so that next time it is required I will save some time? And hence this is not really an issue regarding memory leak?

Comment: Could it also be that the GC hasn't gotten around to freeing the object? Maybe check the profiler to see if the memory usage is really that much of a concern. I'd rule out a leak if repeated calls don't drastically increase memory usage.

Comment: I am not sure what dotmemory exactly shows. But if you use Windbg you can filter only for the live objects with !DumpHeap -stat -live. Anyway you can repeat the steps and do a Heap diff with dotMemory to check if your suspected leaked object count increases. It can also help to load much data into your controls to make leaks more obvious.